# Codeigniter foreach Select Menu 'Selected' Option

Tags: database, codeigniter, html-select

I am creating a theme select option for an App. I want the user to choose from a select option which theme they want, light or dark.

I am storing theme names in the database like so:

[image: database]

I am then calling all themes in the Model and returning the array with this code:

```
public function getThemes() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM theme');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I am using my Constructor to grab the data and Render it to my settings view like so: (I am sending a few things at the same time in $this->data that's why it is in an array but I cut that code out)

```
$this->data = [
            'themes' => $this->model_setting->getThemes()
        ];
        $this->render('backend/standart/administrator/setting/setting_general', $this->data);
```

In my HTML View I have the following HTML which successfully displays the correct 2 themes available:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Select Your Desired Theme</label><br>
                <select class="form-control" name="site_color_theme" id="site_color_theme">
                  <?php foreach ($themes as $theme): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $theme['theme']; ?>" ><?= $theme['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

When I save the settings form I am updating my options table in the database with the theme name. The Html Body Class calls on this options table and finds the chosen theme and uses this to render a specific CSS Stylesheet.

The problem I am having is when I save my settings, the Select Option does not display the saved theme name to show that this is the active theme chosen.

How can I get the Select Option to display the chosen theme when the user visits the settings page to select another theme?

Comment: please check if you have database caching activated.  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html

Comment: `The problem I am having is when I save my settings, the Select Option does not display the saved theme name to show that this is the active theme chosen`: would reload (F5) the page work for you? if yes a simple redirect saves you a lot of struggling

Comment: Hello Vickel, nice to see you again, I was thinking about using the simple redirect option lol I just prefer to struggle for perfection, but I thank you for your kind comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should have `active_theme` column in the `theme` table
2. `active_theme` set to `1` when form dropdown `site_color_theme` is submitted (the rest theme records set to `0`)
3. You should use Codeigniter Form Helper to do that : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_dropdown

```php
// $themes = Theme list array [id => theme-name, id => theme-name]
// $active_theme = Record of "active_theme" with value equal to "1" 
// $extra = Custom HTML attributes e.g. class="something" onclick="function(js)"

echo form_dropdown('site_color_theme', $themes, $active_theme, $extra);
```

Comment: Thank you Murzid, Form Helper was the answer there ;) Thank you for your kind support!